# Combinators for A => Option[A] in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, combinators

Suppose I have `type X[A] = A => Option[A]` and need functions like these:

```
def repeat[A](xa: X[A], n: Int): X[A] // call xa n times  
def many[A](xa: X[A]): X[A]           // call xa until it returns None
```

Does `scalaz` (or any other libraries) provide such functions ?

P.S. As it was mentioned in the comments, the `many` function is only useful for side effects, so it's not a very good example.

Comment: not sure about that as `Scalaz` prefers to work with pure functions, so `repeat`/`many` wouldn't make any sense

Comment: @dk14 Sure, `many` can only be useful for its side effects, but there are perfectly reasonable pure use cases for `repeat`.

Comment: @dk14 and Travis, you are right about `many`. I probably need smth. like `until[A](xa: X[A], pred: A => Boolean): X[A]` to call `xa` until `pred` is true

Comment: @TravisBrown only if it's lifted to something like `Kleisli` (or some kind of free monad is used), anyway +1 to your answer

Comment: @dk14 My understanding is that in `repeat` the function is to be iteratively called on the previous result, in which case it makes sense exactly as is.

Comment: @dk14 I'm not sure I understand. Suppose we have a `safeTimes2` of type `X[Int]` that returns `None` in the case of overflow and double the input otherwise. It's perfectly reasonable to want to apply that iteratively `n` times, even with `X` as given here.

Comment: @TravisBrown sorry, my understanding was wrong, I thought that the request was to repeat it without chaining

Comment: The many is really confusing (at least for me), maybe we remove it from the question as it doesn't relate much to Scalaz. And add some examples like increment.

Comment: @dk14 I agree that `many` is not a good example. I wrote about it the comments. I will update the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you represent your `X` as Scalaz's `Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?], A]`, you get a useful monoid instance:

```
def repeat[A](
  f: Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?], A],
  n: Int
): Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?], A] = List.fill(n)(f).suml
```

(Note that I'm using kind-projector here for convenience—you could also write out the type lambdas.)

As Kenji notes in a comment, you could also use `multiply`:

```
def repeat[A](
  f: Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?], A],
  n: Int
): Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?], A] =
  Monoid[Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?], A]].multiply(f, n)
```

This is the same monoid but a little more efficient.

That doesn't really help with `many`, though (which can only be useful for its side effects). Off the top of my head I can't think of any elegantly abstract way to define it, but a simple recursive implementation isn't too bad:

```
def many[A](f: A => Option[A]): A => Option[A] = new Function[A, Option[A]] {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def apply(a: A): Option[A] = f(a) match {
    case None => None
    case Some(v) => apply(v)
  }
}
```

If you're not worried about stack overflow this could of course be a lot simpler.

Comment: Monoid#multiply is more efficient rather than Foldable#suml https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/988/files

Comment: @TravisBrown shouldn't we ask for monoid's instance in your updated code example, like `def repeat[A, M <: Endomorphic[Kleisli[Option, ?, ?]: Monoid, A]](f: M, n: Int): M = implicilty[Monoid[M]].multiply(f, n)`? didn't check that code though...so just a guess

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out: with Scalaz/Cats you can write a pure version of many

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

def many[F[_] : Monad,A](xa : A => F[Option[A]])(a : A) : F[None.type] = xa(a) >>= {
  case None    => implicitly[Monad[F]].point(None)
  case Some(y) => many(xa)(y)
}
```

This can be very handy if the effetcs you want are more than single-threaded io. Note that the return type `F[None.type]` reflects the specification.

Answer (score -4):

Is something like

```
 def repeat[A](xa: X[A], n: Int): X[A] =  { a => 
   (1 to n).foldLeft(Option(a)) { case(a,_) => 
      a.flatMap(xa(_))
   }
}
```

not hardcore enough for a real programmer?

Comment: if the one isn't a functional programmer

Comment: side-effects aren't; if the function has no side-effects (doesn't produce/ doesn't rely on - referentially transparent), all those loops do not make any sense - the result is gonna be same, no matter how many times you repeat

Comment: That's wrong. You are supposed to be calling `xa` on the result of the previous call.

Comment: Your second implementation isn't valid Scala code, while your first doesn't do what the OP intends it to do (at least on my reading).

Comment: @dk14 No, the result of the function may be different from its argument, so if you call the function on the result of the previous call, you'd get a different result.

Comment: @Kolmar my understanding of the question was wrong, I thought that the request was to repeat it without chaining.

Comment: @dk14 what side effects are you talking about?

Comment: @Kolmar xa takes `A`, result of previous call is `Option[A]`, you can't call xa on it. Perhaps, the author meant to ask something else, like Travis suggests, but I am not clairvoyant.

Comment: @Dima let's say we have `repeat(a => Some(-a), 100500)(1)`, so we passed a pure function here, so no matter 100500 or 9001 - you're getting -1. The only way to avoid it is to make your function rely on some side effects like `var z = 0; a => {z += 1; z * 2}`

Comment: @dk14 my implementation does not have any side effects. The function, passed in, probably, does ... In real life, any useful program would have at least one function with side effects (io), so, you have to accept it as "necessary evil". ;)

Comment: @Dima but the question is about Scalaz and functional programming, so see my first comment ;)

Comment: Well, the next function should be called not exactly on the *result* of the previous call, but on the *contents* of the result `Option`. I believe that's the natural interpretation of the OP's question, because that's the only way the `repeat` function would make sense for pure computations.

Comment: @Kolmar I was confused by `many` as it didn't make any sense for  pure functions (if it's using a previous call) so I concluded the same about `repeat`, sorry again :)

Comment: @Kolmar, I don't think it is so "natural", because, for example, it does not explain what to do if xa returns None. In any case, my point stands. Just replace `map` with `foldLeft`. Updating the answer ...

Comment: @Dima Your updated implementation doesn't compile. That's why people are using libraries for that "to not reinvent the wheel", "to not burn your fingers twice (te zhe grabli)"

Comment: @dk14 really? You are going to be picking on a typo?  (fixed now).
The point is that this implementation is _shorter_, than, for example, Travis' using the library. So, if by "burning your fingers" you mean making a typo, then my approach wins ;)

Comment: @DIma so, you had to check it before using, right? the point is same

Comment: @Dima Travis's implementation is `List.fill(n)(f).suml` which is much shorter and more readable even with lifting to a Kleisli

Comment: @dk14 not if you include the `def ...` ... And the phD diploma required for a reader to figure out how to call that function ;)
"I had to check..." what?

Comment: @Dima scalaz tag on the question assumes smthng like that, or just expirience. I don't have PhD diploma btw and too much expirience with scalaz neither

Comment: @dk14 I know it assumes that ... I am just saying, it should not. That was exactly the point: this use case is not right for scalaz. Perhaps, you need to get a diploma in sarcasm studies ;)

Comment: @dima so this is not the answer to the question, finally we agree!!

Comment: @dk14 I don't know what you are talking about. Sure, it is.

Comment: @Dima "Does scalaz (or any other libraries) provide such functions ?"

Comment: @dk14  The answer is "no, and you don't need it". If you ask me how to prove a pythagorean theorem using tensor analysis, and I show you the actual proof, would that also not answer the question? Does the second part of Travis' answer answer the question?

Comment: @Dima but no one is seems to agree with your answer. Anyway, my time for "Someone is wrong on the internet" is over :)

Comment: @dk14 If by "no one" you mean "neither yourself nor Travis", then yeah ... However "someone is wrong" and "someone disagrees with Travis" aren't really equivalent predicates are they? Also, "I disagree with this" and "this doesn't answer the question" aren't synonymous either, are they?

Comment: @Dima I don't understand what you're saying, could you please clarify?

Comment: @dk14 I am saying, that disagreeing with Travis  (or yourself) doesn't necessarily equal to being wrong. Therefore, your statement "no one agrees with your answer" is hardly a valid argument for any point.
Is it more clear now?

Comment: @Dima sorry it's not

Comment: @dk14 I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @Dima I mean Idn what you're talking about

Comment: @dk14 I don't understand what you are saying, sorry.